# Error separating a directory containing image files and xml annotation files into train and test sets

Tags: xml, pytorch, annotations, pytorch-dataloader, train-test-split

Currently trying to split a directory including both jpg image files and relevant xml annotations into train and test sets. I am currently attempting two methods, one of which stated first considers all jpg and xml files in the same directory 'data_source_path', whilst the second attempts via pre-segregated jpg and xml subdirectories. I am getting an error which I don't specifically understand, as the file stated as missing is not present, whether in the first or subsequent two xml/jpg folders. Not sure what to do and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example 1 - splitting directory including all jpg and xml files:

```
for image_file in os.listdir(data_source_path):

    labels_file = image_file.replace('.jpg', '.xml')

    if random.uniform(0, 1) > 0.2:

        shutil.copy(data_source_path + image_file, train_images + image_file)
        shutil.copy(data_source_path + labels_file, train_images + labels_file)

    else:

        shutil.copy(data_source_path + image_file, test_images + image_file)
        shutil.copy(data_source_path + labels_file, test_images + labels_file)
```

Example 2 - splitting separate sub-directories including all jpg and xml files:

```
for image_file in os.listdir(image_path):

    labels_file = image_file.replace('.jpg', '.xml')

    if random.uniform(0, 1) > 0.2:

        shutil.copy(image_path + image_file, train_images + image_file)
        shutil.copy(annot_path + labels_file, train_annotations + labels_file)

else:

        shutil.copy(image_path + image_file, test_images + image_file)
        shutil.copy(annot_path + labels_file, test_annotations + labels_file)
```

The error is specified as follows:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0f4b02788990> in <cell line: 21>()
     26 
     27         shutil.copy(data_source_path + image_file, train_images + image_file)
---> 28         shutil.copy(data_source_path + labels_file, train_images + labels_file)
     29 
     30     else:

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    252         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    253     else:
--> 254         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    255             try:
    256                 with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/satellite_multi_class/data/000002754 (2).xml'
```